# Receiving error on android studio installation

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to install android studio to my brand new macbook and receiving this error.

Tried to install both of them:
android-studio-2021.2.1.15-mac.dmg

Mac with Apple chip
android-studio-2021.2.1.15-mac_arm.dmg

No result. Three more days trying to install idea to start working facing dead end. Located in kyrgyzstan, Is google restricted some of resources for certain countries or why does it happening, have no clue, no idea, i thought using vpn but also don't know how to do it. The error is (android studio setup wizard):

Preparing "Install Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 6)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/arm64-v8a-33_r06.zip
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image: Connection reset.
"Install Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 6)" failed.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image: Connection reset.

Preparing "Install Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 6)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/arm64-v8a-33_r06.zip
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image: Connection reset.
"Install Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 6)" failed.
Android Studio setup was canceled

Comment: Did you figured it out? I am getting the same error on my mac.